# Convert JSONObject which contains \" to a normal string with JSON

Tags: java, json

I receive a string from an http request which contains data such as:

```
{"status":1,"Type":3,"Data":"<p style=\"padding-left:80px\"><\/p><ol><li><span style=\"color:#ff0000\">This<\/span><\/li><li>is a<\/li><li><strong>m<span style=\"background-color:#66cc00\">are<\/span><\/strong><\/li><\/ol><p><\/p><p style=\"padding-left:80px\"><strong style=\"text-align:left\"><span style=\"background-color:#66cc00\"><\/span><\/strong><\/p>  "}
```

I convert it to a JSONObject like so:

```
jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
```

I then need to get the html as a String to display in a TextView,

I have tried this:

```
String data = jsonObj.getString("data");
```

but data remains null. This works with simple json strings, but i think it might be cause of the " characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `"data"` with a lowercase `d`, but your JSON contains `"Data"` with a capital `D`. Use this:

```
jsonObj.getString("Data");
```

Comment: How embarrassing, Total Noob error cost me many hours. Thanks for the sharp eye.

Answer (score 3):

You have used `"data"` instead of `"Data"`. This is the only silly mistake you did. To avoid such type of typo mistake, always user `final static String` to access them from anywhere.

```
final static String KEY_DATA = "Data";
```

Then access it inside your class (suppose class name is `Aclass`):

```
jsonObj.getString(KEY_DATA);
```

And in other classes:

```
jsonObj.getString(Aclass.KEY_DATA);
```

This is a good practice indeed and no possibility of typo mistake!

Comment: No, todays most used IDEs are smart enough. A `ctrl+space` will show you suggestion to pick of your choice in windows. No need to type variable name. Also if you make typo mistake, IDE will show `syntax` error on your variable name. At least it is safe than typing same string `"Data"` everywhere.

Comment: No, silly, you make the typo in `final static String KEY_DATA = "data";`